# Passing an element name using a variable in VBA

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

I have a multi page element on a MS Access form and I am trying to use GetArgs to identify which page to open using the below code.

```
Dim WrdArray() As String
If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
    LoadAndLocation = Me.OpenArgs
    WrdArray() = Split(LoadAndLocation, "|")
    OriginalPage = WrdArray(1) 'Results in the correct page name, e.g. Fina
    Me.OriginalPage.SetFocus 
End If
```

How do I convert the page name to a format Access will accept?

Answer (score 0):

Tumbleweed badge aside :) I found out  that I needed to refer to the tab control BEFORE I refer to the page I wanted. I have added the line
  `Dim OriginalPage as String` and replaced `Me.OriginalPage.SetFocus` with `Me.tabDeposits.Pages(OriginalPage).SetFocus` and it ran immediately.